A first order theory of $\mathbb{R}$
The properties that $\mathbb{R}$ should satisfy can be summarized as "Dedekind complete ordered field".
The axioms of ordered fields are first-order sentences.
I came up with a first-order version of the Dedekind completeness.
It is the following axiom schema. Let $l(x)$ and $u(x)$ be first-order formulas with a real variable $x$ witch satisfy $\exists xl(x), \exists xu(x), \forall x (l(x)\vee u(x))$ and $\forall x\forall y(l(x)\wedge u(y)\rightarrow x<y)$, then $\exists z (l(z)\wedge \forall x(l(x) \rightarrow x\leq z))\vee \exists z (u(z)\wedge \forall x(u(x) \rightarrow x\leq z))$.
I would guess that this is weaker than the set-theoretic definition but most of the usual real number theory can be developed with it.
Is there a theorem that can be proved with the usual real number theory but cannot be proved with this first-order real number theory?

FYI: by Löwenheim–Skolem, any first-order theory of "real numbers" has models of any infinite cardinality, thus it cannot describe the usual real numbers only.

If I understand it correctly, the issue is basically the difference between axiom schemas vs quantifiers over predicates (i.e second order logic; see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3141984/axiom-schemas-vs-second-order-axioms-which-first-order-predicates-exist). Your $l(x)$ and $u(x)$ can only be formulas definable in the language of your theory, of which there are only countably many. The true Dedekind completeness is defined in terms of arbitrary subsets, not just definable ones.

I suspect this is strictly weaker than the theory of real closed fields? For example, I'm not entirely sure you can prove even any positive number has a square root in this system. But if they are actually equivalent, then any first-order property of real numbers must be provable in your system as well, since the theory of real closed fields is just the complete first-order theory of $\mathbb{R}$.

@DavidGao I think this theory can do the usual proof that any positive number $a$ has  square root: Apply the completeness schema with $l(x)$ being $(x<0)\lor(x^2<a)$ and $u(x)$ being $\neg l(x)$. On the basis of this example, I've convinced myself that zeros of odd-degree polynomials can be produced similarly, and so I think this theory is equivalent to the theory of real-closed fields.

@AndreasBlass There's a subtlety here about whether $l$ and $u$ are allowed to use parameters or not. If parameters are allowed, the theory is equivalent to RCF, by your argument. But without parameters, the theory is weaker than RCF, as shown by Taranovsky here. I'll write an answer to this effect.

@AlexKruckman As you pointed out, I was assumiing parameters are allowed.

@AndreasBlass Ah, I see how it works. For some reason I thought you also need to prove Archimedean property before being able to use that argument to produce square roots. (I thought one needs something like, if $y$ is the minimal element with $u(y)$ but $y^2 > a$, then for sufficiently large $n$, $y - \frac{1}{n}$ must have square still larger than $a$. I don't know why I didn't realize $\frac{1}{n}$ can just be replaced by an arbitrarily small positive element...) But yeah, I think I'm also convinced that this is equivalent to RCF. I suppose I'll wait for Alex's answer to formalize this.

The first-order theory of $\mathbb{R}$ is well-understood. It is one of the oldest and most important examples in the field of model theory.
An ordered field $R$ is real closed if every positive element in $R$ has a square root in $R$ and every polynomial of odd degree in $R[x]$ has a root in $R$. Tarski proved in 1930 that the theory of real closed fields is complete and decidable. In particular, any first-order sentence true in $\mathbb{R}$ is provable from RCF.
So let's compare this with the theory you proposed. An ordered field satisfying your condition is called definably complete.
Actually, the definition of definably complete is usually given as follows: For every first-order formula $\varphi(x)$, if the set defined by $\varphi(x)$ is non-empty and bounded above, then it has a least upper bound. Formally, we have the axiom $$(\exists x\, \varphi(x)\land \exists y\,\widehat{\varphi}(y))\to \exists z\, (\widehat{\varphi}(z)\land \forall w\, (\widehat{\varphi}(w)\to z\leq w)),$$ where $\widehat{\varphi}(y)$ is the formula expressing that $y$ is an upper bound for $\varphi$: $$\forall x\, (\varphi(x)\to x\leq y).$$
The equivalence of the two definitions of "definably complete" is easy to see. The least upper bound version implies your version by taking $\varphi(x)$ to be $l(x)$. And your version implies the least upper bound version, by taking $l(x)$ to be $\exists y\, (\varphi(y)\land x\leq y)$ and $u(x)$ to be $\lnot l(x)$.
Now there are actually two different versions of definable completeness, depending on whether the formulas are allowed to have parameters or not. For example, to modify the least upper bound version to allow parameters, we should really work with formulas of the form $\varphi(x,\overline{p})$ (where $\overline{p} = (p_1,\dots,p_n)$ is a tuple of variables of arbitrary length) and modify the axiom scheme to $$\forall \overline{p}\, ((\exists x\, \varphi(x,\overline{p})\land \exists y\,\widehat{\varphi}(y,\overline{p}))\to \exists z\, (\widehat{\varphi}(z,\overline{p})\land \forall w\, (\widehat{\varphi}(w,\overline{p})\to z\leq w))),$$ where $\widehat{\varphi}(y,\overline{p})$ is: $$\forall x\, (\varphi(x,\overline{p})\to x\leq y).$$
The theory of ordered fields which are definably complete (allowing parameters) is equivalent to the theory of real closed fields. This was sketched in the comments by Andreas Blass and explained in more detail by Asaf Karagila here.
The theory of ordered fields which are definably complete (without parameters) is strictly weaker than the theory of real closed fields. This was shown by Dmytro Taranovsky here. He uses forcing to construct a definably complete (without parameters) ordered field containing a positive element with no square root.

Is there a theorem that can be proved with the usual real number theory but cannot be proved with this first-order real number theory?


If "theorem" means "sentence of first-order logic in the language of ordered rings which is true in $\mathbb{R}$" and "definably complete" allows parameters, the answer is no. Every theorem is provable from the theory of real closed fields, and therefore also from the theory of definably complete ordered fields.

If "theorem" means "sentence of first-order logic in the language of ordered rings which is true in $\mathbb{R}$" and "definably complete" does not allow parameters, the answer is yes: take the statement that every positive element has a square root. Taranovsky's answer linked above provides a countermodel.

If "theorem" means "theorem about $\mathbb{R}$ in set theory / higher order logic", the answer is yes: take (second-order) completeness. Any first-order theory of $\mathbb{R}$ has countable models by Löwenheim-Skolem, which cannot be complete.



In your description of Taranovsky's result, "real closed" should presumably be "ordered".  +1, in particular for the information about that result.

@AndreasBlass Fixed, thanks!
